# Wrong sign for cohen.d {psych} in R?

Tags: r, effect-size, cohens-d

I'm trying to calculate Cohen's d with cohen.d from the {psych} package in R. So this is the descriptives output (means of variables for groups):

```
    > cohen.d[["descriptive"]][["mean"]]
       GROUP  DTT_SUM  TRU_SUM MOT_M_SUM MOT_X_SUM  ABI_SUM BENINT_SUM
NoIAPs     1 18.24204 8.140127  23.38854  26.41401 12.59236   32.12739
IAPs       2 18.45752 7.660131  25.52288  25.98039 12.56209   30.23529
```

When looking at the effect size output (below), for some reason the signs seem to be wrong. What should be a negative d is positive and vice versa.
Did I make a mistake with my input? Is it a bug? Am I just being stupid?

```
> cohen.d(Ttestdatanoout, "GROUP")
Call: cohen.d(x = Ttestdatanoout, group = "GROUP")
Cohen d statistic of difference between two means
               lower effect upper
    DTT_SUM    -0.18   0.04  0.26
    TRU_SUM    -0.33  -0.10  0.12
    MOT_M_SUM   0.03   0.26  0.48
    MOT_X_SUM  -0.29  -0.06  0.16
    ABI_SUM    -0.23  -0.01  0.22
    BENINT_SUM -0.41  -0.19  0.04
```

P.S. I know that there is other packages that can compute Cohen's d (or I could type out the formula manually) but if possible, I would like to use {psych}.

Comment: If you don't like the sign, why not just switch the roles of the two groups?

Comment: Well, it's not that I don't "like" the sign. I just thought that _d_ should be negative when _M1_ < _M2_ and positive when _M1_ > _M2_ . But this is not the case here. Hence my question. It's really a technical question concerning the specific cohen.d {psych} function.

Comment: My point is that it seems to be nothing other than what convention for comparison is followed by that function--and even if it differs from what you expect, you already have the answer.